# Beforehand? Am I wrong to say “I lived in the US beforehand”?

Tags: word-usage

Is it wrong to say “I lived in the US beforehand”?

In dictionary, Beforehand means “in advance” as in “rooms must be booked beforehand.” But I was wondering if It is awkward to say “I lived in the US beforehand.”

Comment: It would make no sense unless you explained what or where it was that followed your stay in the United States. It would also not be idiomatic. Beforehand is generally used to refer to events/visits/tasks and the like rather than periods in which you lived somewhere, Prefer **previously** or **earlier**.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sure.

Yes, beforehand means "in advance", and refers to some performing something in advance of performing a task. If you're saying "I lived in the US beforehand", then "living in the US" is a preparation for something. For instance, "I entered the deep fried food cooking competition,  but I lived in the US beforehand, so I had experience cooking that way."

Of course, jokes about American cuisine aside, living somewhere is rarely relevant to a task, so it's not typically used that way.